# Select first nested child in list but not subchilds

Tags: css, nested, css-selectors, html-lists

I have a unordered list like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Element one
        <ul>
            <li><a>Element two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Element three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now if I try to select the `<a>`-element of "Element two". I would do it like the following:

```
ul ul li:first-child > a
```

This will select also the following nested `<a>` element. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/38ksdpw3/

How can this be solved?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_combinators.asp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably need to add an identifier to the first `<ul>` element and then walk through the children tree by `parent > child` [children selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/38ksdpw3/1/)**

```css
ul.main > li > ul > li:first-child > a {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: @julmot The `.main` identifier in this case acts as a *start point* which makes the selector start from that level in the DOM to match the the desired element at the end.

Comment: Ok now I got it! The problem is without adding a class the selector will also be correct for the nested a-elements. Thank you!

Comment: @HashemQolami, if the `ul` is a direct child of the body, you could also use `body > ul > li > ul > li:first-child > a` instead of an extra class. Or when the list has a parent, you could use: `.parentClass > ul > .....`

Comment: @LinkinTED Absolutely. What I meant was having an identifier to determine the first `<ul>`. Either by giving it an ID, Class ro targeting it by `body > ul`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can not diffirintiate it in such structure. For both links you have `ul ul li:first-child > a` applied without the specific parent. So you should consider to use classes (at least for parenting) instead of tags.