# What is the CSS selector for what I'm trying to do?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have two different "*layers*" (What's the correct terminology???) of `ul`s and I want to select the `a` tags which are only within first one.

```
<div>
   <ul> 
       <li>
           <a>Here's what I'm trying to apply a certain style to</a>
           <ul>
                <li>
                     <a>Here's what I'm not trying to apply that certain style to</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

       </li>

   </ul>
</div>
```

So I know I can't just do `div ul li a` because that would include the inner `a` tags.

Comment: Have a look at: [Select first nested child in list but not subchilds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887234/select-first-nested-child-in-list-but-not-subchilds/25887335#25887335)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

- Use child combinators
- Reference the div element

Such:

```
div > ul > li > a
```